# Strip text of all formatting on paste

Tags: c#, jquery, tinymce

I have an application that allows the user to create an article.  The problem arises when the user pastes from something like Word which comes loaded with a bunch of markup.

I'm using a jQuery editor called tiny_mce which allows the markup.  I do a htmlencode and decode obviously but it means that i carry a huge payload of markup.

Is there a way to strip (all) markup from pasted text and just keep the text?

Or is there a way that tiny_mce can show the markup as text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's been a while since I used tinyMCE, but when I did I used [this paste plugin](http://wiki.moxiecode.com/index.php/TinyMCE:Plugins/paste) that did automatic clean-up on paste, including paste from Word.

Answer (score 0):

Strip all HTML markup using Regex: http://weblogs.asp.net/rosherove/archive/2003/05/13/6963.aspx

```
string stripped = Regex.Replace(textBox1.Text,@"<(.|\n)*?>",string.Empty);
```

This Regex expression can be applied to the language of choice.

Answer (score 0):

I use a simple Windows shell addin caled [Pure Text](http://www.stevemiller.net/puretext/.).  It overloads the Windows+V key to do a plain text paste.